# emmc drivers kernel linux crash when it is configured as loadable module

Tags: c, kernel-module, mmc, qualcomm

I have make a change to have mmc drivers loadable kernel module but I got a kernel crash when I tried to unload `mmc_host_module` using `rmmod mmc_host_module`.

NB: I have deactivated `CONFIG_MMC_CLKGATE`.

All insert command work correctly:

```
insmod mmc_core.ko
insmod mmc_block.ko
insmod sdhci.ko
insmod shdci_pltfm.ko
insmod mmc_host_module.ko
```

But when I tried to unload mmc_host_module I got the following errors directly after removing the module :

```
mmc0: Reset 0x1 never completed.
mmc0: Reset 0x1 never completed.
mmc0: Reset 0x1 failed with workaround
```

After that I got from crash dump (dmesg):

```
114.044574:   <6>  mmc0: In suspend emmc_reset_gpio: 51, val: 0 
114.049031:   <6>  mmc0: In suspend emmc_reset_gpio get_value: 0
116.708652:   <6>  mmc0: emmc_reset_gpio: 51, val: 1 
116.712232:   <6>  mmc0: In resume emmc_reset_gpio get_value: 1
117.051544:   <6> mmc0: _mmc_resume: awake failed (-110), fallback to full init
119.846145:   <6> mmc0: card 0001 removed
124.841021:   <6> ------------[ cut here ]------------
124.841081:   <6> WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 1830 at drivers/mmc/host/sdhci-msm.c:2596 sdhci_msm_check_power_status+0xd4/0x124 [mmc_host_module]()
124.841091:   <2> mmc0: request(1) timed out waiting for pwr_irq
124.841098:   <2> Modules linked in: mmc_host_module(-) sdhci_pltfm sdhci mmc_block mmc_core .......... # I have removed the rest of line 
124.841177:   <6> CPU: 0 PID: 1830 Comm: rmmod Tainted: G     U         3.18.48LE
124.841208:   <2> [<c00141d0>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c0011fd4>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14)
124.841225:   <2> [<c0011fd4>] (show_stack) from [<c001f4f8>] (warn_slowpath_common+0x6c/0x84)
124.841240:   <2> [<c001f4f8>] (warn_slowpath_common) from [<c001f540>] (warn_slowpath_fmt+0x30/0x40)
124.841266:   <2> [<c001f540>] (warn_slowpath_fmt) from [<bf26130c>] (sdhci_msm_check_power_status+0xd4/0x124 [mmc_host_module])
124.841326:   <2> [<bf26130c>] (sdhci_msm_check_power_status [mmc_host_module]) from [<bf23a5a8>] (sdhci_reset+0x78/0x220 [sdhci])
124.841351:   <2> [<bf23a5a8>] (sdhci_reset [sdhci]) from [<bf239038>] (0xbf239038)
124.841375:   <2> [<bf239038>] (0xbf239038) from [<bf23dcc8>] (sdhci_set_ios+0x6c/0xb4 [sdhci])
124.841400:   <2> [<bf23dcc8>] (sdhci_set_ios [sdhci]) from [<bf23db2c>] (sdhci_request+0x898/0x9c8 [sdhci])
124.841424:   <2> [<bf23db2c>] (sdhci_request [sdhci]) from [<bf23dc84>] (sdhci_set_ios+0x28/0xb4 [sdhci])
124.841528:   <2> [<bf23dc84>] (sdhci_set_ios [sdhci]) from [<bf2d2dac>] (mmc_set_ios+0x2c/0x120 [mmc_core])
124.841627:   <2> [<bf2d2dac>] (mmc_set_ios [mmc_core]) from [<bf2d490c>] (mmc_check_bkops+0xd4/0xf4 [mmc_core])
124.841717:   <2> [<bf2d490c>] (mmc_check_bkops [mmc_core]) from [<bf2d6c14>] (mmc_stop_host+0x13c/0x144 [mmc_core])
124.841807:   <2> [<bf2d6c14>] (mmc_stop_host [mmc_core]) from [<bf2d7e28>] (mmc_remove_host+0x28/0x60 [mmc_core])
124.841865:   <2> [<bf2d7e28>] (mmc_remove_host [mmc_core]) from [<bf23a1e0>] (sdhci_remove_host+0x68/0x280 [sdhci])
124.841896:   <2> [<bf23a1e0>] (sdhci_remove_host [sdhci]) from [<bf261b58>] (sdhci_msm_remove+0x60/0x1f0 [mmc_host_module])
124.841923:   <2> [<bf261b58>] (sdhci_msm_remove [mmc_host_module]) from [<c02c4b1c>] (platform_drv_remove+0x18/0x30)
124.841939:   <2> [<c02c4b1c>] (platform_drv_remove) from [<c02c2ff8>] (__device_release_driver+0x88/0xf4)
124.841953:   <2> [<c02c2ff8>] (__device_release_driver) from [<c02c36c8>] (driver_detach+0x9c/0xa4)
124.841966:   <2> [<c02c36c8>] (driver_detach) from [<c02c2b80>] (bus_remove_driver+0x4c/0xa0)
124.841980:   <2> [<c02c2b80>] (bus_remove_driver) from [<c0065a90>] (SyS_delete_module+0x134/0x1c8)
124.841996:   <2> [<c0065a90>] (SyS_delete_module) from [<c000e4dc>] (__sys_trace_return+0x0/0x24)
124.842005:   <6> ---[ end trace f9057010bff1a7d5 ]---
125.652365:   <6> mmc0: Reset 0x1 never completed.
125.655605:   <6> mmc0: waiting for SW_RST_REQ is successful
130.680118:   <6> ------------[ cut here ]------------
130.680172:   <6> WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 1830 at drivers/mmc/host/sdhci-msm.c:2596 sdhci_msm_check_power_status+0xd4/0x124 [mmc_host_module]()
130.680181:   <2> mmc0: request(1) timed out waiting for pwr_irq
130.680190:   <2> Modules linked in: mmc_host_module(-) sdhci_pltfm sdhci mmc_block mmc_core .......... # I have removed the rest of line 
130.680268:   <6> CPU: 0 PID: 1830 Comm: rmmod Tainted: G     U  W      3.18.48LE.UM.1.2-78600-9x07-174-g3e3630e-dirty #118
130.680298:   <2> [<c00141d0>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c0011fd4>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14)
130.680315:   <2> [<c0011fd4>] (show_stack) from [<c001f4f8>] (warn_slowpath_common+0x6c/0x84)
130.680330:   <2> [<c001f4f8>] (warn_slowpath_common) from [<c001f540>] (warn_slowpath_fmt+0x30/0x40)
130.680356:   <2> [<c001f540>] (warn_slowpath_fmt) from [<bf26130c>] (sdhci_msm_check_power_status+0xd4/0x124 [mmc_host_module])
130.680393:   <2> [<bf26130c>] (sdhci_msm_check_power_status [mmc_host_module]) from [<bf23a5a8>] (sdhci_reset+0x78/0x220 [sdhci])
130.680417:   <2> [<bf23a5a8>] (sdhci_reset [sdhci]) from [<bf239038>] (0xbf239038)
130.680440:   <2> [<bf239038>] (0xbf239038) from [<bf23dcc8>] (sdhci_set_ios+0x6c/0xb4 [sdhci])
130.680465:   <2> [<bf23dcc8>] (sdhci_set_ios [sdhci]) from [<bf23db2c>] (sdhci_request+0x898/0x9c8 [sdhci])
130.680490:   <2> [<bf23db2c>] (sdhci_request [sdhci]) from [<bf23dc84>] (sdhci_set_ios+0x28/0xb4 [sdhci])
130.680596:   <2> [<bf23dc84>] (sdhci_set_ios [sdhci]) from [<bf2d2dac>] (mmc_set_ios+0x2c/0x120 [mmc_core])
130.680691:   <2> [<bf2d2dac>] (mmc_set_ios [mmc_core]) from [<bf2d490c>] (mmc_check_bkops+0xd4/0xf4 [mmc_core])
130.680781:   <2> [<bf2d490c>] (mmc_check_bkops [mmc_core]) from [<bf2d6c14>] (mmc_stop_host+0x13c/0x144 [mmc_core])
130.680871:   <2> [<bf2d6c14>] (mmc_stop_host [mmc_core]) from [<bf2d7e28>] (mmc_remove_host+0x28/0x60 [mmc_core])
130.680930:   <2> [<bf2d7e28>] (mmc_remove_host [mmc_core]) from [<bf23a1e0>] (sdhci_remove_host+0x68/0x280 [sdhci])
130.680962:   <2> [<bf23a1e0>] (sdhci_remove_host [sdhci]) from [<bf261b58>] (sdhci_msm_remove+0x60/0x1f0 [mmc_host_module])
130.680990:   <2> [<bf261b58>] (sdhci_msm_remove [mmc_host_module]) from [<c02c4b1c>] (platform_drv_remove+0x18/0x30)
130.681006:   <2> [<c02c4b1c>] (platform_drv_remove) from [<c02c2ff8>] (__device_release_driver+0x88/0xf4)
130.681020:   <2> [<c02c2ff8>] (__device_release_driver) from [<c02c36c8>] (driver_detach+0x9c/0xa4)
130.681034:   <2> [<c02c36c8>] (driver_detach) from [<c02c2b80>] (bus_remove_driver+0x4c/0xa0)
130.681048:   <2> [<c02c2b80>] (bus_remove_driver) from [<c0065a90>] (SyS_delete_module+0x134/0x1c8)
130.681064:   <2> [<c0065a90>] (SyS_delete_module) from [<c000e4dc>] (__sys_trace_return+0x0/0x24)
130.681073:   <6> ---[ end trace f9057010bff1a7d6 ]---
131.491258:   <6> mmc0: Reset 0x1 never completed.
131.494497:   <6> mmc0: Reset 0x1 failed with workaround
131.499269:   <6> sdhci: =========== REGISTER DUMP (mmc0)===========
131.499278:   <6> sdhci: Sys addr: 0x00000000 | Version:  0x00002e02
131.499287:   <6> sdhci: Blk size: 0x00004000 | Blk cnt:  0x00000000
131.499296:   <6> sdhci: Argument: 0x00000000 | Trn mode: 0x00000000
131.499305:   <6> sdhci: Present:  0x01f80000 | Host ctl: 0x00000000
131.499314:   <6> sdhci: Power:    0x00000000 | Blk gap:  0x00000000
131.499322:   <6> sdhci: Wake-up:  0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00000003
131.499331:   <6> sdhci: Timeout:  0x00000000 | Int stat: 0x00000000
131.499340:   <6> sdhci: Int enab: 0x00000000 | Sig enab: 0x00000000
131.499348:   <6> sdhci: AC12 err: 0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x00000000
131.499357:   <6> sdhci: Caps:     0x262dc8b2 | Caps_1:   0x00008007
131.499366:   <6> sdhci: Cmd:      0x00000000 | Max curr: 0x00000000
131.499375:   <6> sdhci: Resp 1:   0x00000000 | Resp 0:   0x00000000
131.499383:   <6> sdhci: Resp 3:   0x00000000 | Resp 2:   0x00000000
131.499391:   <6> sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x00000000
131.499401:   <6> sdhci: ADMA Err: 0x00000000 | ADMA Ptr: 0x00000000
131.499409:   <6> ----------- VENDOR REGISTER DUMP -----------
131.499420:   <6> Data cnt: 0x00000000 | Fifo cnt: 0x00000000 | Int sts: 0x000c0000
131.499430:   <6> DLL cfg:  0x60006400 | DLL sts:  0x00000000 | SDCC ver: 0x1000002e
131.499440:   <6> Vndr func: 0x00018a1c | Vndr adma err : addr0: 0x00000000 addr1: 0x00000000
131.499448:   <6> Vndr func2: 0xfa8218a8
131.499513:   <6>  Test bus[0 to 3]: 0x0000c846 0x000000ce 0x00006010 0x018001ff
131.499523:   <6>  Test bus[4 to 7]: 0x00063dd0 0x0004c030 0x00000000 0x0003ffff
131.499532:   <6>  Test bus[8 to 11]: 0x47fc1604 0x40800002 0x2003e089 0x00000cc0
131.499542:   <6>  Test bus[12 to 15]: 0x004f0408 0x801f0180 0x0d000000 0x00000ab6
131.499551:   <6>  Test bus[16 to 19]: 0x00000000 0x000f800c 0x00000000 0x00000091
131.499560:   <6>  Test bus[20 to 23]: 0x0240ff01 0x00050021 0x00000000 0x00000000
131.499569:   <6>  Test bus[24 to 27]: 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
131.499578:   <6>  Test bus[28 to 31]: 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
131.499586:   <6>  Test bus[32 to 35]: 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
131.499595:   <6>  Test bus[36 to 39]: 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
131.499604:   <6>  Test bus[40 to 43]: 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
131.499613:   <6>  Test bus[44 to 47]: 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
131.499622:   <6>  Test bus[48 to 51]: 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
131.499631:   <6>  Test bus[52 to 55]: 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
131.499640:   <6>  Test bus[56 to 59]: 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
131.499650:   <6> mmc0: clk: 0 claimer: rmmod pwr: 12 host->irq = 0
131.499658:   <6> mmc0: rpmstatus[pltfm](runtime-suspend:usage_count:disable_depth)(2:1:1)
131.499666:   <6> sdhci: ===========================================
136.560108:   <6> ------------[ cut here ]------------
136.560158:   <6> WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 1830 at drivers/mmc/host/sdhci-msm.c:2596 sdhci_msm_check_power_status+0xd4/0x124 [mmc_host_module]()
136.560167:   <2> mmc0: request(1) timed out waiting for pwr_irq
136.560174:   <2> Modules linked in: mmc_host_module(-) sdhci_pltfm sdhci mmc_block mmc_core .......... # I have removed the rest of line 
136.560285:   <6> CPU: 0 PID: 1830 Comm: rmmod Tainted: G     U  W      3.18.48LE
136.560316:   <2> [<c00141d0>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c0011fd4>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14)
136.560332:   <2> [<c0011fd4>] (show_stack) from [<c001f4f8>] (warn_slowpath_common+0x6c/0x84)
136.560346:   <2> [<c001f4f8>] (warn_slowpath_common) from [<c001f540>] (warn_slowpath_fmt+0x30/0x40)
136.560373:   <2> [<c001f540>] (warn_slowpath_fmt) from [<bf26130c>] (sdhci_msm_check_power_status+0xd4/0x124 [mmc_host_module])
136.560409:   <2> [<bf26130c>] (sdhci_msm_check_power_status [mmc_host_module]) from [<bf23af5c>] (sdhci_get_cd+0x210/0x29c [sdhci])
136.560434:   <2> [<bf23af5c>] (sdhci_get_cd [sdhci]) from [<bf23db54>] (sdhci_request+0x8c0/0x9c8 [sdhci])
136.560458:   <2> [<bf23db54>] (sdhci_request [sdhci]) from [<bf23dc84>] (sdhci_set_ios+0x28/0xb4 [sdhci])
136.560558:   <2> [<bf23dc84>] (sdhci_set_ios [sdhci]) from [<bf2d2dac>] (mmc_set_ios+0x2c/0x120 [mmc_core])
136.560653:   <2> [<bf2d2dac>] (mmc_set_ios [mmc_core]) from [<bf2d490c>] (mmc_check_bkops+0xd4/0xf4 [mmc_core])
136.560741:   <2> [<bf2d490c>] (mmc_check_bkops [mmc_core]) from [<bf2d6c14>] (mmc_stop_host+0x13c/0x144 [mmc_core])
136.560830:   <2> [<bf2d6c14>] (mmc_stop_host [mmc_core]) from [<bf2d7e28>] (mmc_remove_host+0x28/0x60 [mmc_core])
136.560888:   <2> [<bf2d7e28>] (mmc_remove_host [mmc_core]) from [<bf23a1e0>] (sdhci_remove_host+0x68/0x280 [sdhci])
136.560920:   <2> [<bf23a1e0>] (sdhci_remove_host [sdhci]) from [<bf261b58>] (sdhci_msm_remove+0x60/0x1f0 [mmc_host_module])
136.560947:   <2> [<bf261b58>] (sdhci_msm_remove [mmc_host_module]) from [<c02c4b1c>] (platform_drv_remove+0x18/0x30)
136.560962:   <2> [<c02c4b1c>] (platform_drv_remove) from [<c02c2ff8>] (__device_release_driver+0x88/0xf4)
136.560975:   <2> [<c02c2ff8>] (__device_release_driver) from [<c02c36c8>] (driver_detach+0x9c/0xa4)
136.560988:   <2> [<c02c36c8>] (driver_detach) from [<c02c2b80>] (bus_remove_driver+0x4c/0xa0)
136.561002:   <2> [<c02c2b80>] (bus_remove_driver) from [<c0065a90>] (SyS_delete_module+0x134/0x1c8)
136.561016:   <2> [<c0065a90>] (SyS_delete_module) from [<c000e4dc>] (__sys_trace_return+0x0/0x24)
136.561026:   <6> ---[ end trace f9057010bff1a7d7 ]---
```

I think this error is related to `static void sdhci_msm_check_power_status(struct sdhci_host *host, u32 req_type)` and `void sdhci_reset(struct sdhci_host *host, u8 mask)` functions. have any suggestions/solutions to fix this kernel issue ?

NB: I have the same source in this link https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/+/android-msm-marlin-3.18-nougat-dr1/drivers/mmc, you can see host/sdhci-msm.c, host/sdhci.c, core/core.c, core/host.c

**UPDATE:**

in sdhci-msm.c: in sdhci_msm_remove() function that is called in rmmod, `readl_relaxed(host->ioaddr + SDHCI_INT_STATUS)` returns always 0, I think it is the root cause of kernel crash

```
static int sdhci_msm_remove(struct platform_device *pdev)
{
    struct sdhci_host *host = platform_get_drvdata(pdev);
    struct sdhci_pltfm_host *pltfm_host = sdhci_priv(host);
    struct sdhci_msm_host *msm_host = pltfm_host->priv;
    struct sdhci_msm_pltfm_data *pdata = msm_host->pdata;
    int dead = (readl_relaxed(host->ioaddr + SDHCI_INT_STATUS) ==
            0xffffffff); 
    //readl_relaxed(host->ioaddr + SDHCI_INT_STATUS) returns always 0 have an explanation why ?
    pr_err("%s: %s :: readl_relaxed(host->ioaddr + SDHCI_INT_STATUS) = 0x%x", dev_name(&pdev->dev), __func__, readl_relaxed(host->ioaddr + SDHCI_INT_STATUS));
    pr_debug("%s: %s\n", dev_name(&pdev->dev), __func__);
    if (!gpio_is_valid(msm_host->pdata->status_gpio))
        device_remove_file(&pdev->dev, &msm_host->polling);
    device_remove_file(&pdev->dev, &msm_host->msm_bus_vote.max_bus_bw);
    pm_runtime_disable(&pdev->dev);
    sdhci_remove_host(host, dead);
    sdhci_pltfm_free(pdev);
    if (gpio_is_valid(msm_host->pdata->status_gpio))
        mmc_gpio_free_cd(msm_host->mmc);
    sdhci_msm_vreg_init(&pdev->dev, msm_host->pdata, false);
    sdhci_msm_setup_pins(pdata, true);
    sdhci_msm_setup_pins(pdata, false);
    if (msm_host->msm_bus_vote.client_handle) {
        sdhci_msm_bus_cancel_work_and_set_vote(host, 0);
        sdhci_msm_bus_unregister(msm_host);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is the source for this module?

Comment: Please include your [mcve] _in the body of the question_ as [help] says.

Comment: So the only change you have made is to the kernel configuration to build the `sdhci-msm` driver as a loadable module instead of a built-in driver?

Comment: yes, and i have deactivated CONFIG_MMC_CLKGATE

Comment: Congratulations, you found a bug in the driver. Presumably no-one has tested such configuration (module). I can open your eyes by telling that approx. 50% drivers in kernel like this...